# Change parameter for infinity scroll module

Tags: javascript, drupal, request, infinite-scroll, form-data

I have 'Infinite scroll' module for Drupal 7.

Here's code js code from this module.

```
(function ($) {
  "use strict";

  var $window = $(window);

  // The threshold for how far to the bottom you should reach before reloading.
  var scroll_threshold = 200;
  var vis_index = 0;

  /**
   * Insert a views infinite scroll view into the document after AJAX.
   *
   * @param {object} $new_view The new view coming from the server.
  */
  $.fn.infiniteScrollInsertView = function ($new_view) {
  var $existing_view = this;
  var $existing_content = $existing_view.find('.view-
content').children();
  $new_view.find('.view-content').prepend($existing_content);
$existing_view.replaceWith($new_view);
$(document).trigger('infiniteScrollComplete', [$new_view, $existing_content]);
};

/**
 * Handle the automatic paging based on the scroll amount.
*/
Drupal.behaviors.views_infinite_scroll_automatic = {
attach : function(context, settings) {

  var settings = settings.views_infinite_scroll;
  var loadingImg = '<div class="views_infinite_scroll-ajax-loader"><img src="' + settings.img_path + '" alt="loading..."/></div>';

  $('.pager--infinite-scroll.pager--infinite-scroll-auto', context).once().each(function() {
    var $pager = $(this);
    $pager.find('.pager__item').hide();
    if ($pager.find('.pager__item a').length) {
      $pager.append(loadingImg);
    }
    $window.bind('scroll.views_infinite_scroll_' + vis_index, function() {
      if (window.innerHeight + window.pageYOffset > $pager.offset().top - scroll_threshold) {
        $pager.find('.pager__item a').click();
        $window.unbind('scroll.views_infinite_scroll_' + vis_index);
      }
    });
    vis_index++;
   });
  }
 };
})(jQuery);
```

After button click some request sending via Ajax and my page has this Form data:

```
view_name:blog
view_display_id:page
view_args:
view_path:about/media
view_base_path:about/media
view_dom_id:a2acec59ca7b252cfd911b770bc558bc
pager_element:0
page:2
```

I need to change this `page` parameter. How can I find him?
I something is unclear, please say me in comments. I'll try to provide you with all needed information.

Comment: maybe you can use `vis_index` ?

Answer (score 1):

I have a dirty solution which could work for you. You can use hook_init to change the received parameters in the $_SERVER. Just take care enough to change this PAGE parameter when strict conditions are met, otherwise you could end up with a very strange behaivour.

Another way to change this value is using views hooks. See here: https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7.x-3.x

And just as a last resort, you can use Javascript to change the pager data on the link before it's pressed.

Hope that help.